# Mean and variance of a Random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, means, variance

I am trying problem no. 2 from [Purdue HW here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece302/homeworks/OldHomeworks/hw4_sol.pdf) .

> Balls are drawn from an urn containing $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls until a white ball appears. Find the mean value $m$ and variance $σ^2$ of the number of black balls drawn, assuming each ball is placed back into the urn after being drawn. (In other words, for each attempt we have $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls in the urn.)

I did not understand the part in the solution that says "the mean and variance of $Y$ are $\frac{1}{p}$ and $\frac{1}{p^2} − \frac{1}{p}$, respectively".  $Y$ is a Bernoulli variable. Shouldn't the mean be $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$??

> And if I had to solve the same problem without replacement of balls how would I solve it?

I tried solving it by taking an example like $3$ white and $3$ black balls. And I got a mean of $$\frac{3}{6} + \frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}= \frac{3}{4}$$ which seems correct to me.
But how do I express the same in terms of variable of $w$ and $b$?

Comment: No, $Y$ is geometric. It is stated in the text.

Comment: Right. I missed it.

Comment: (Concerning without replacement) Actually you used the legitimate equation $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pr(X\geq n)$ to find the mean. It is correct.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it is not providing a closed formula for mean and variance.